# How to dynamically set the type of constructor function method in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to create a class or constructor function, which I specify a list of values to be used in the type of one of it's methods.

As an example I have this code.

```js
const MyAnimal = function (animal: string[]) {
  type Animal = typeof animal[number]

  this.getAnimal = (url: Animal) => {
    console.log(url)
  }
}

const animalTest = new MyAnimal(['sheep', 'dog', 'cat'])
// I would like this to fail as 'mouse' is not part of the array ['sheep', 'dog', 'cat']
animalTest.getAnimal('mouse')
```

I want getAnimal to have the type `'sheep' | 'dog' | 'cat'` and for the intellisense to warn me if I add something different

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that via a generic type parameter and a `readonly` array of animals, like this;

```typescript
class MyAnimal<Animal> {
    constructor(public animals: readonly Animal[]) {
    }
    getAnimal(url: Animal) {
        console.log(url);
    }
}

const animalTest = new MyAnimal(['sheep', 'dog', 'cat'] as const);
animalTest.getAnimal('mouse'); // Error as desired
animalTest.getAnimal('sheep'); // Works
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=40&pln=11&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBBAdgSwLZhAHhRrAfNAN4BQ0F0wA9shAC4BOArsPdYwBQAOzARiFTBoYNJhAQAXNEYBTMABNaIeNDziA2gF0AlCXKUAvgYoBzWfXVZOzRiGlWQespVdVaEaiFkA6ENVMbOx0AbhNoY2NSGjp6ETEsABVZBmgAXmhkWQB3OCQEkE4NAHIIAAtZWW5igBpoYqVTWvrgMHpirREYGIZQ0lF8EGSGH3NLAs5i9GpmCFli0OgAeiXoAFFGRg4u6AUU1DkFfoLh+lGLR0nyyurFlegAdQ4AawhSIA)

TypeScript can infer the string literal union type to provide as the type argument for the `Animal` type parameter because the array is `readonly` (which we satisfy when calling the constructor via `as const`), so TypeScript knows it won't change at runtime.

Comment: Amazing thank you so much for your reply.. as a next step - is there a way to instead of passing in an array of strings, to pass in an array of objects, where the objects contain a string you want to infer as the type, e.g. { name: 'tiger', url: 'https:....' }, { name: 'sheep', url: 'https://...' }

Comment: @user3284707 - Sure, TypeScript can infer that, too, you just specify the shape of the objects in terms of the `Animal` type parameter: https://tsplay.dev/mqQZ2m

Comment: This is almost exactly what I need, other than I need to try and now pass in an array of items rather than having them hard coded like in your example.  Is this possible, when I have tried it's come back as unknown

Comment: I have tried here but it's not working any ideas? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBUIGcwB50B8yA3gFDLIhwC2EAXMuqQL6mkIA2cWWyAsgE8AgiGDU4HXCLESiZCggD2IHFACuCMIqjIAFAAc1AIw7AEyOKPEcsDAEoQ4AE2UdhUKHAG4M2PNOsCAgBKEnJkVnCAcwgwAIk9KloGeI5Q+QpkJRVFDggAOg5FKN0kiGDw1kjsnGQIAA9IKCoOABlgWoBeZABtcIyKMoYAciwACwgIfWHKgBp+8MGaemRhlyiZimZ5igHKZZGEODBNiNIAXTYasAsrCUwuyggAd35hO45dHvyfhqaW9o4c4WXjXCqkSwyDgPMD5GJxD66YbURRqLAQYahAD0WOQADlFDdoFBtKAosg6LoIR8YXDYqkkeNJtNsbiAOraADWWCAA

Comment: @user3284707 - You can't do this with dynamic data, because types are a compile-time concept in TypeScript. See the note at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In order to infer literal type, you can use [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types):

```js
type Animal<Name extends string> = {
    name: Name,
    url: `https://${string}`
}

class MyAnimal<
    Name extends string,
    Item extends Animal<Name>,
    List extends Item[]
    > {
    constructor(public animals: [...List]) {
    }

    // You should get "url" from infered list and not from Item["url"]
    getAnimal<Url extends List[number]['url']>(url: Url) {
        console.log(url);
    }
}

const animalTest = new MyAnimal(
    [
        { name: 'sheep', url: 'https://sheep.com', },
        { name: 'dog', url: 'https://dog.com', },
        { name: 'cat', url: 'https://cat.com', }
    ]);

animalTest.getAnimal('https://dog.com'); // ok
animalTest.getAnimal('https://mouse.com'); // expected error
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WoJ0em)

If you want to learn more about literal type inference, you can check my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments). The goal is to provide as much as possible constraints to generic parameter. If there are enough constraints TS will infer literal type.

Comment: AMAZING Thank you so much